# connection doesn't close mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Need some help. Can't close the connection. On close the result returns as undefined

```
function(table, where, to_select, callback) {
    db.open(function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        if (!err) {
            collection = db.collection(table);
            collection.find(where, to_select).toArray(function(err, resp) { console.log(resp); //returns undefined
                callback(err,resp); 
            })
        } else {
            callback(err);
        }     
        db.close();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You close your db too early when the query is still processing. Therefore, postpone closing the connection until your query is done and you have the results in the callback like so

```
function(table, where, to_select, callback) {
    db.open(function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        if (!err) {
            collection = db.collection(table);
            collection.find(where, to_select).toArray(function(err, resp) { console.log(resp); //returns undefined
                db.close();                    
                callback(err,resp);     
            })
        } else {
            callback(err);
            db.close();
        }     
    });
}
```

Comment: It works, but I'm still getting (node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 reconnect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

Comment: Well that's a completely other issue not related to your mongoDB question which should be a dedicated question as you will have to show other parts of your code as well

Comment: OK, thanks. Can you please help with it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39433733/warning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-reconnect-listeners-adde